# Uploading multiple files in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot

I am stuck with uploading multiple files in ReactJS. I have uploaded a single file before as shown with the codes below. I used sessionStorage to be able to view the files binaryString.

```
<input
type="file"
onChange={(evt) => {

    let files = evt.target.files;
    let file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
            let binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            const image = btoa(binaryString);
            const formattedImage = 'data:image/octet-stream;base64,' + image;
            isLoad = true
            sessionStorage.setItem('load', JSON.stringify(isLoad))
            SingleImageBase64Model.setSingleImageBase64(formattedImage);
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);


        if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('load')) === true) {
            this.setState({ isImageLoaded: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ isImageLoaded: false });
        }
    }
}} />
```

Today, I'd love to upload multiple files. The data will be sent to a Restful web-service written in Java (Spring Boot). Currently, I have the following in ReactJS and has not worked for uploading multiple files.

```
// In return method, HTML for file-picker
<input
type='file'
multiple
onChange={this.onFileChange} />

// Function for handling file/s uploads
onFileChange = (event) => {
const fileData = event.target.files;
const blob = new Blob([fileData]);
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {

        console.log('Data to be sent', {
            name: fileData[i].name,
            fileSize: fileData[i].size,
            fileContentType: fileData[i].type,
            file: reader.result
        });
    }
}
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); }
```

My problem is with the **reader.result**, it returns the same binaryString data as shown on the console log.

[image]

The above code, if the document upload works! Will be formatted accordingly to accept my backend request (web-service) for saving multiple files.

Backend model is as follows.

```
@Entity
public class Document implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String name;
private String description;
@Lob
private byte[] file;
private int fileSize;
private String fileContentType;

// constructors
// getter and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for that you need to use for loop. In my case I have used.

```
<input
  type='file'
  multiple
  onChange={this.onFileChange} />

onFileChange = () => {

  let filesArray = e.target.files;
  let array = [];

  for (var i=0; i<filesArray.length; i++) 
  {
      let fileObj = {
         name: filesArray[i].name,
         fileSize: filesArray[i].size,
         fileContentType: filesArray[i].type,
         file: filesArray[i].result
      }
      array.push(filesArray[i]);
      reader.readAsText(filesArray);
  }

  this.setState({ uploadedFiles: array })
```

hope this will help you. I used for loop for that.